# Using Meteor and socket.io together

Tags: node.js, socket.io, meteor

I am newbie about `Meteor`.

I am developing a `realtime multiplayer game`. I want to implement everything about the game but game engine states with `Meteor`. For example chat messages, available game rooms, invitations, online members etc. I want to make those functionalities with`Meteor`.

But I want to implement game states manually without `Meteor` with `socket.io`.  Because, the game is real time and every 45 msec(in my architecture), game states will be streaming to the clients and I think Meteor is not for this and not flexiable. So I developed multiplayer concept and synchronising clients and server with `socket.io`. There is no problem about it.

I want to use `Meteor` and `socket.io` both and together. I tried to implement it. I installed `socket.io` with `npm` inside `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app` under my meteor app. After that I include `require` statement on `server side Meteor startup`;

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    var require = Npm.require;
    var sio = require('socket.io')
    var socketIO = sio.listen(this.http)

    socketIO.configure(function () {

       socketIO.set('log level', 0);

       socketIO.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
        callback(null, true); // error first callback style
     });

     socketIO.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
     socketIO.set("polling duration", 30);

});

socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log(client.id + ' is connected')
    client.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(client.id + ' is diconnected')
    });
})})
```

And I put the connection statement on `client side Meteor startup`;

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  socket = io.connect();

  socket.on('connect', function () {
     console.log('connecting');
  });
})
```

On client side, `io` variable is not defined error is occurred. This is seen to me that,`Meteor` does not import client side `socket.io.js` on client side. So I tried to put `socket.io.js` manually under clients folder to load it on client side. This is not good way I know, I should not do this. But, even I do and client loads it, there is another client side error about transport variable of `io` for the statement;

```
io.transports.push('xhr-polling');
```

It says that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`. Somehow, client side `socket.io.js` can not be loaded properly.

I could not find an example for usage of Meteor and socket.io together. Is there a simple way to use them both together?

Thank you!

Comment: "game states will be streaming to the clients and I think Meteor is not for this and not flexiable." What? That's exactly what Meteor does. There is no reason to use socket.io if you are using Meteor. Meteor's reactivity uses WebSockets and/or a fallback if WebSockets is unavailable. You should publish the game state on the server, and subscribe to the game state on the clients. Whenever the game state changes on the server, it will be automatically pushed to all the subscribed clients in real-time. No socket.io needed.

Comment: But my game is on canvas. I thought that Meteor is not effective for canvas operation. It is seen mostly for DOM elements to me.

Comment: Transferring data between the server and clients has nothing to do with DOM or canvas. Either way, you're just sending JSON objects across the network. Once the client has received the update, it can display it however it wants: HTML, SVG, canvas, whatever. You can use [observe callbacks](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) to keep track of changes on the collection and update the canvas.

Comment: In fact, if you read Meteor's documentation, under "Seven Principles of Meteor", the very first principle is "Data on the Wire. Don't send HTML over the network. Send data and let the client decide how to render it."

Comment: To add on to what @Cuberto said, Meteor supports WebSockets using sock.js rather than socket.io.  There is some overhead in the DDP protocol, as you would expect for any abstraction, so if you don't need the useful parts that DDP provides, you can use your own.  For your particular use-case, you may find this package useful: http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/   In particular, check out the blackboard drawing example: http://blackboard.meteorhacks.com/vutLGkeJuGEzsJa2f

Comment: Actually I thought that Meteor could create some overhead as you said, cause data streaming will be in so small time period (like 45 msec as I mentioned in question.). But @Cuberto 's comments made me think about it and try to make it with Meteor. I will test whether Meteor can create overhead about performance or not and I'll see what is gonna be happened.

Comment: @AhmetDAL There could be some overhead with DDP, though I don't think it should be too much. If you are planning to send the entire game state every 45ms, that would probably cause a lot more overhead than DDP, as you would be sending data that might not even have changed. DDP will send updates only as the data changes, which can definitely work with a lot of game designs.

Comment: @Cuberto I am developing my initial game to test. I really wish, you are right :) . Thank you both for helping me.